# Experience Cloud - Custom Object List View not showing records

Tags: custom-object, experience-cloud

I have a Custom Object, called Program.

In Salesforce, I have a set of list views created for the Program Object, including one that shows "All" programs (see below)[image]

The sharing settings on the list view is [image: all users can view the list view]

On Experience Cloud, I created a Record List view for the Program.

**While my user can see the "All Programs" List view, no programs are actually visible for my user (see below, for the empty list view)**[image]

I looked at Setup > Profiles and my user profile, to make sure that the user profile had Read access to the Program, which it does (see below)[image]

**What would be the next place to check?**

Comment: - Review the organization-wide default (OWD) and the sharing rules for the object.
- if the OWD is set to Private or Public Read Only, you may need to create or edit the sharing rules to grant access to the user or the user's role, group, or territory.
- If the OWD is set to Public Read/Write or Public Read/Write/Transfer, you may need to check the record owner or the manual sharing of the records to see if the user has access to them.

Comment: Hi @TusharJadav - thank you! That was it, the OWD sharing settings (found under Setup > Sharing Settings, for future readers), was set to Private, which is why this wasn't visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Review the **Organization-Wide Default (OWD)** and the **Sharing Rules** for the object.
- If the **OWD** is set to `Private` or `Public Read Only`, you may need to
  create or edit the sharing rules to grant access to the user or the
  user's role, group, or territory.
- If the **OWD** is set to `Public Read/Write` or `Public Read/Write/Transfer`, you may need to check the
  record owner or the manual sharing of the records to see if the user
  has access to them.
- You can find OWD sharing settings under **Setup** > **Sharing Settings**